# Laravel @extends failing to pull in master layout

Tags: php, laravel-4, extends, laravel-blade

While creating a basic item detail page for a basic blog I've run into a problem with Laravel's @extends not working when pulling in a master layout template. The content from the detail page loads just fine but the master page HTML is not there at all and I'm not getting any errors.

In my routes:

```
Route::get('blog', 'BlogController@public_index');
Route::get('blog/{id}', 'BlogController@public_single');
```

In my BlogController:

```
public function public_single($id) {
    $blog = Blog::find($id);
    return View::make('public.blog_single') -> with('blog', $blog);
}
```

At the very top of the blog_single template:

```
@extends('layouts.public')
```

All other templates that use this master layout work as expected.

My views directory structure:

```
views
  |
  |layouts
  |    |
  |    | admin.blade.php
  |    | public.blade.php
  |
  |public
      |
      |blog.blade.php
      |blog_single.blade.php
```

One thing I'm wondering is if the fact that this page looks like it's rendering from a subdirectory is an issue. Here is an example:

This works:

```
www.mydomain.com/blog
```

This doesn't:

```
www.mydomain.com/blog/1
```

I've looked through the Laravel docs and don't see an answer there. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: what is your file and directory structure in /app/views/ ? please update your question.

Comment: Do you have a route `Route::get('blog', 'aControler');` ?

Comment: @Gadoma, I've included it above.

Comment: @Fractaliste, Yes I have that, I added it above to the question. I did not add it the first time since it works and I did not want to confuse the subject more than it already was.

Comment: You said `All other templates that use this master layout work as expected`, so what is the difference between this (`blog_single`) and other views ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera, They are identical in structure except for the content they pull in. That is why I'm wondering about the subdirectory issue that I mentioned in the last 5 lines of my question.

Comment: I have even tried copy/pasting the blog.blade.php file into the blog_single.blade.php file and I get the same results, no master page for the blog_single page.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to add an absolute path to the master style references?

For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Has to be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

In all the url's we use. This worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, not sure how this fixed it, hopefully someone can give me a little detail.

I found this line of code at the bottom of the blog_single.blade.php file:

```
<div class="text-center">{{ $blogs->links() }}</p>
```

That is leftover from a copy/paste of the blog.blade.php file and obviously on a detail page I don't need pagination. 
I removed that one line of code and now the templates work as they should. Wondering why Laravel did not throw some sort of error if it was choking on that line, or why that line would effect the whole master file from getting included in the first place.

Anyway, it's fixed.